# htaccess Redirect 301 directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've read many things about this, but none seems ok at the moment.
I've to redirect:
http://mysite.it/255-dir-name/
to:
http://mysite.it/forum/255-dir-name/

Also, everything which is in this directory must be redirected to the new path.

I've tried with this, but doesn't work:
`RewriteRule ^255-dir-name/(.*)$ /forum/255-dir-name/$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Is there any .htaccess inside `/255-dir-name/` also?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^255-dir-name(.*) http://example.it/forum/255-dir-name/$1 [R,L]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.

**Warning!** When you test the rewrite, do so in a NEW browser, or fully clear its cache. That is because your previous `301` redirect has been cached by your browser, so your browser does not even request the page from your server anymore. Instead, it requests the previous rewrite directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the first url to the second url with the following directives in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+-[^/]+/?)$ forum/$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect any url that starts with one or more numbers, a dash, and then one or more non-slash characters to the forum-url.